# Homebrew Formula settings to deploy binaries based on destination environment

Tags: operating-system, homebrew, graalvm-native-image

I have a minimal homebrew formula deploying a Java application (built with GraalVM).

The associated executable has been built on a MAC OSx machine with Intel architecture and is wrapped in a targz archive.

```
class MyApp < Formula
  desc "MyApp description"
  url "https://github.com/account/myapp/releases/download/0.4/myapp-0.4.tar.gz"
  sha256 "..."
  license "Apache-2.0"
  def install
    libexec.install Dir["*"]
    bin.install_symlink libexec/"myapp"
  end
end
```

I got users asking to use the same recipe on different environments:

- Linux (with a brew linux)
- Mac OS.X M1 (application executable would be different)

Whereas I know how to build the executables for different plaforms and create the different `myapp-osx-intel-0.4.tar.gz`, `myapp-osx-m1-0.4.tar.gz`,`myapp-linux-0.4.tar.gz`, I do not find any existing formula that would test destination environment and copy proper archive.

Looking at the documentation I find the notion of [bottles](https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles) but the bottle names seems to be a cross-over with architecture and operating system.